# Change Font Family of the title of the Window WPF C#

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

How to change the font family of a Window in WPF,Other than creating a template for the Window and using it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use this in Application.Resources:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily"
        Value="Cambria" />
    </Style>
```

And add this in the Window constructor after the InitializeComponent:

```
Style = (Style)FindResource(typeof(Window));
```

Pretty straightforward.

Or maybe use this in the same constructor after the InitializeComponent:

```
 Application.Current.MainWindow.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Cambria");
```

**Note:** For the second approach you don't need that Style anymore.

[See windows font families here:](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/)

**Edit 1**

Unfortunately i wasn't paying maximum attention on what you are asking. Indeed there is not an easy way to accomplish that. I don't know what have you found or done until now but i used once [this project](http://web.archive.org/web/20081006142447/http://blog.opennetcf.com/ayakhnin/PermaLink,guid,23a7be17-d833-4e45-b498-34ef04d98cb2.aspx) and it behaved well.

Another example would be this. I didn't try it but looks promissing: [WPF Custom Chrome Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/131515/WPF-Custom-Chrome-Library)

Indeed a lot of work is needed for that.

From MSDN :

> The non-client area of a window is implemented by WPF and includes the
>   parts of a window that are common to most windows, including the
>   following:
>
> ```
> A border.
>
> A title bar.
>
> An icon.
>
> Minimize, Maximize, and Restore buttons.
>
> A Close button.
>
> A System menu with menu items that allow users to minimize, maximize, restore, move, resize, and close a window.
> ```

And those "non-client" areas are controlled by windows.

Comment: hi Mircea, I tried the above, the style is applied to all the elements of the Window,yet the Window title is still the default font